# Fetching data from Social (Facebook, LinkedIN) through Auth.Providers without creating/updating any users

Tags: force.com-sites, authentication, social

I have a **public site** hosted in Salesforce, reachable from another domain.

On the site, I have a registration form when I'd like to implement the following feature:

- possibility to pre-compile some form's fields by fetching them from LinkedIN or Facebook.

By studying docs, I found the `Auth.RegistrationHandler` interface, that allows to redirect to FB/LinkedIN, login there and then fetch some UserData, but this process is designed to end with the user creation/update on Salesforce, so for making a login on a Salesforce community.

My need, instead, is to only read the user data (email, firstname, lastname) and then put them on the form. The user creation is something I handle by myself (or better, I don't perform it, I only create an account by data in the form).

So I think it's not possibile to reach my goal by using this interface. Is there any other way to accomplish that?

Thanks you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr answer**

No, the standard SF methods do not support that, you would have to build your own code to retrieve the data from Facebook or LinkedIn and then create the user with an Apex class.

**Using SF standard Auth handler functions**

When you are setting up the Authorisation Providers where it asks for the registration handler you can provide custom Apex code rather than relying on that provided as a default by Salesforce.

This will need to create an SF user with the minimum details -Last name, Alias, Email address, Username, and nickname. It will also need to provide licence type and profile for the user record. So it looks like you cannot avoid the user creation step completely. [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=sso_authentication_providers.htm&type=0) for this and [Auth class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthConfiguration.htm#apex_class_Auth_AuthConfiguration) developer's guide.

So you are correct in assuming the default methods do create the user based on the auth provider profile and these methods are not able to be passed alternative information. It would be possible to have a page where the user enters details which can be passed in to the Apex class for the user record creation along with the required details from the auth provider for authentication, but the standard RegistrationHandler interface does not support that.

> **createUser(portalId, userData)**
>
> Returns a User object using the specified portal ID and user
>   information from the third party, such as the username and email
>   address. The User object corresponds to the third party’s user
>   information and may be a new user that hasn’t been inserted in the
>   database or may represent an existing user record in the database.

Comment: I don't need to create an user, my form has to aim to create an account.. I already tried to experiment by writing a custom class that implement that interface, but its use is not what I need.

Comment: Will your form be in Salesforce or external to it? Also do you want to use LinkedIn or FB as auth providers or just data sources?

Comment: My site is exposed on Salesorce, it is a SF Site. The question is exactly this: I don't want to use them as auth providers but only as data source. SF, instead, as far as I know, provides tools (e.g. the Auth.RegistrationHandler interface) to handle what I don't need (i.e. using Social as Auth. Providers)..

Comment: Ok, added to the answer. In short the standard methods do not support what you want to do so you will have to write your own.